# Rest API, file generation on client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, fabricjs, jspdf

I have an asp.net core website with a controller that return a View with a viewmodel.

This view generate a pdf on javascript using jsPdf. I can't perform the pdf generation on server side because i'm using a client side componnent (fabric.js)

I would like to expose an API to be able to download this pdf.

When i hit my end point with a browser, the pdf file is downloaded correctly.
When i'm using postman or a WebClient in c#, i can't get the pdf...
I guess i'm missing something. The Test method does not work, i have a pdf but i can't open it, it's only 15ko :(

My view :

```
<script src="/Scripts/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {});
    canvas.loadFromJSON(@Html.Raw(Model.Json),
        () => {
            canvas.setWidth(@Model.Width);
            canvas.setHeight(@Model.Height);
            var imgData = new Image();
            imgData.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
            imgData.src = canvas.toDataURL('png');
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [@Model.Width, @Model.Height]);
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 1, 1, @Model.Width, @Model.Height, 'Mockup', 'NONE', 0);
            pdf.save('myMockup.pdf');
        }
    );  
</script>
```

My controller :

```
    public IActionResult Generate(int id)
    {
        var mockup = DynamicValueAppService.ParseMockup(id);
        var mockupVM = new MockupGeneratorViewModel()
        {
            Width = mockup.Width,
            Height = mockup.Height,
            Json = JObject.Parse(mockup.Json)
        };
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
        return View(mockupVM);
    }


    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFile("http://localhost:21021/Mockup/generate/1", @"C:\mum.pdf");
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Comment: Postman and WebClient will not run the javascript in your view they will just download the view as html, no clientside processing of javascript will happen. If you want an API to have an endpoint that will download a PDF then the PDF will need to be generated server side. Or you would have to browse to the url that will create the pdf clientside and then upload the result of that somewhere for the API to then serve.

Comment: Well, thanks you for your answer i'm diging on node services ...